# Best certification for requesting disability accommodations for GRE?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, disability

I am planning to take the GRE Subject Test in Math. I have ADHD and would like to request accommodations.

I live in a first world country now but used to be based in a third world country. In this third world country I was seeing a resident psychiatrist.

I am about to have a new psychiatrist who is not a resident.

This psychiatrist has met me for only an hour while my old psychiatrist , the resident, met with me for over 12 hours already.

What certification should I submit to ETS?

new doctor only? Old doctor though resident only? Both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow [the instructions given by ETS](https://www.ets.org/disabilities/documentation/documenting_adhd/). They are very specific about what kind of documentation they need.

Give your current psychiatrist the link and ask if he/she can provide everything on it, and if not, what he/she recommends you do to collect the necessary documentation.

Comment: Thank you, ff524. This was actually a stupid question because I should have just and later asked ETS who advised me to submit from both psychiatrists.

Comment: @JackBauer - This is useful information and I suggest you post it as an Answer.

Comment: @aparente001 Done!

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a stupid question because I should have just asked (and later I did ask) ETS, who advised me to submit from both psychiatrists.

Comment: Please fill in the missing word: "should have just" *what*?

Comment: @aparente001 I should have just asked ETS. I later asked ETS. ETS advised me to submit from both psychiatrists

Comment: Good luck.  I still think the jerk, ahem, pardon me, ADHD skeptic, should have been left entirely out of the picture.  He was involved with you such a short time, and his contribution was entirely negative, as far as I could tell.

Comment: @aparente001 Thank you for editing! I didn't submit documentation from ADHD skeptic :)